# Using a controller action on a button click - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Really new to using Ruby on Rails and programming in gentle so apologies in advance if this seems very basic.

I'm working on a very simple wiki based website, where users can upgrade and downgrade their account.

In my `downgrade.html.erb` I have the following code:

```
<p>Are you sure you want to downgrade back to standard?<p>

<%= link_to "Yes", :controller => :charges, :action => :downgrade1, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
<%= link_to "No", root_url, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
```

and in my `charges_controller.rb` I have my *downgrade1* method:

```
def downgrade1
    if current_user.premium?
       current_user.update_attribute(:role, 'standard')
       flash[:success] = "You have been downgraded to standard."
       redirect_to root_url
    else
      false
    end
end
```

Ultimately, when the user clicks that 'Yes' button, I want that `downgrade1` method to run and the user's account to be downgraded back to standard.

However, what happens is the website loads a 'show webpage' with my header and footer, but the user is still a premium user.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your attempts to solve my problem, both your answers eventually led to me finding the solution.

In the end, I used this code in my view:

```
<%= button_to "Yes", { :controller => "charges", :action => "downgrade1"}, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
```

and added this to my routes.rb

```
post "charges/downgrade1" => "charges#downgrade1"
```

Downgrading now works as planned.

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you didn't specify the HTTP method for your `link_to`, like

```
<%= link_to "Yes", :controller => :charges, :action => :downgrade1, class: 'btn btn-danger', :method => :patch %>
```

By default, it will call a GET method, then nothing in your database will be changed.
And make sure you have defined that method in your `routes.rb`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one closing tag at the end of your if - else statement:

```
    else
      false
    end
end
```

Comment: Ah, my apologies, the end closing tag is in my code, I just missed it when copying and pasting to this question. Thank you anyway!